# Selecting and retrieving multiple cells in different rows

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to retrieve multiple cells in different rows where the correct owner exists, but I'm only being able to retrieve the first match and it stops there, I've tried using it with a for, but I don't think .ExecuteScalar() is the way to do this. Maybe I'm just stupid and doing it completely wrong.

Code:

```html
checkPlayerName = API.getPlayerName(player);
string checkOwnedCars = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [carOwners] WHERE Owner='" + checkPlayerName + "'";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand checkCarsCount = new SqlCommand(checkOwnedCars, con);
            int carsCountToVar = Convert.ToInt32(checkCarsCount.ExecuteScalar());
            con.Close();
            for (int i = 0; i < carsCountToVar; i++)
            {
                string displayCars = "SELECT LP FROM [carOwners] WHERE Owner='" + checkPlayerName + "'";
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand displayCarsCMD = new SqlCommand(displayCars, con);
                string displayCarsToVar = displayCarsCMD.ExecuteReader().ToString();
                API.sendChatMessageToPlayer(player, "Owned Vehicle: " + displayCarsToVar.ToString());
                con.Close();
            }
```

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbk8t.png)

For example, LP on 2nd and 3rd row are the ones that I want to store since both belong to the same owner, yet only first cell data (1337) is displaying.

Comment: Where are you setting `checkPlayerName`? Also would *highly* recommend using parameters and not concatenating strings.

Comment: checkPlayerName = API.getPlayerName(player); But the problem ain't there, because I'm able to retrieve the data from the owner, but only retrieving on one row, not others.

Comment: Ok I think I see what's up. You are using the count to attempt to iterate over the LP values from carOwners right? Except you run the same query for the same player each time in the loop. That value won't change, so the result doesn't change. I think you are wanting to iterate over the return values instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not iterating the results you are getting from query.

> Plus always use Parameterized queries to prevent SQL Injection Attacks

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT LP FROM [carOwners] WHERE Owner=@checkPlayerName", con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkPlayerName",checkPlayerName);

using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
  while (reader.Read())
  {
     Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}",reader["id"]));
     //API.sendChatMessageToPlayer(player, "Owned Vehicle: " + reader["id"].ToString());
   }
}

conn.Close();
```

Comment: that `if (reader.Read())` should probably be `while (reader.Read())`

Comment: Nice and concise. Eliminates the need for 2 trips to the database. Incorporates `using` (although OP should also do that for the connection too). Includes parameters instead of concatenation. Good answer.